# Flat list is not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to display a flat list (values form json placeholder) filterable with a search bar and it's not rendering for some reason. The values are not visible. Thanks!

The flat list code:

```jsx
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, FlatList, Button } from "react-native";
import { ListItem, SearchBar } from "react-native-elements";
 
class FlatListDemo extends Component {
 
  constructor(props) {
    super(props); 
  
    this.state = { 
      loading: false,   
      data: [],
      temp: [],
      error: null,
      search: null
    };
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
  }
 
   getData = async ()  => {
    const url = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`;
    this.setState({ loading: true });
      
     try {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const json = await response.json();
        this.setResult(json);
     } catch (e) {
        this.setState({ error: 'Error Loading content', loading: false });
     }
  };
 
  setResult = (res) => {
    this.setState({
      data: [...this.state.data, ...res],
      temp: [...this.state.temp, ...res],
      error: res.error || null,
      loading: false
    });
  }
 
  renderHeader = () => {
      return <SearchBar placeholder="Search Here..."
          lightTheme round editable={true}
          value={this.state.search}
          onChangeText={this.updateSearch} />; 
  }; 
 
  updateSearch = search => {
        this.setState({ search }, () => {
            if ('' == search) {
                this.setState({
                    data: [...this.state.temp]
                });
                return;
            }
             
            this.state.data = this.state.temp.filter(function(item){
                return item.name.includes(search);
              }).map(function({id, name, email}){
                return {id, name, email};
            });
        });
  };
 
  render() {
    return (
      this.state.error != null ?
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'column',justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <Text>{this.state.error}</Text>
          <Button onPress={
            () => {
              this.getData();
            }
          } title="Reload" />
        </View> : 
        <FlatList
            ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
            data={this.state.data}
            keyExtractor={item => item.email}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <ListItem
                roundAvatar
                title={`${item.name}`}
                subtitle={item.email}
            />
        )}
      />
    );
  }
}
 
export default FlatListDemo;
```

Importing this list to:

```jsx
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, StatusBar, SafeAreaView } from "react-native"
import "firebase/auth";
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import "firebase/auth";
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
import FlatListDemo from './FlatListDemo';

const Home: () => React$Node = () => {
    return(
        <>
            <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content"/>
            <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
            <FlatListDemo/> 
            </SafeAreaView>
        </>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

This is what it looks like (values should be there). Using Expo on Android:

[photo1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePQbl.jpg)

Thanks! I appreciate the help!

Comment: Why the mix of class and function components? Also, is `React$Node` even valid? Is that meant to be Typescript?

Comment: @Phil I'll be honest, I'm a complete beginner with React Native. I stitched this up with a few different pieces of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are using a `ListElement` as it is defined in version `1.2.0` of `react-native-elements` but the actual version that you are using is `> 1.2.0`.

You are implementing it similar to [the documentation of react-native-elements 1.2.0](https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/1.2.0/listitem).

However, the definition of `ListItem` [has changed in newer version](https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/components/listitem). In the newest version, the `ListItem` component is just a simple view wrapper. Hence, it needs to contain children in order to display the information that you want.

In your case this could be implemented as follows (I did not know what `roundAvatar` is doing).

```js
 renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <ListItem>
        <ListItem.Content>
          <ListItem.Title>{`${item.name}`}</ListItem.Title>
          <ListItem.Subtitle>{item.email}</ListItem.Subtitle>
        </ListItem.Content>
    </ListItem>
```

Check [the documentation of the newest version](https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/components/listitem) for the exact features that you want to use.